# How do I preprocess templates in a theme file?

Tags: 8, theming

I have created two custom templates (header-before-login.html.twig and header-after-login.html.twig). I would like to get data from the database to pass to these templates using variables.

How can I overwrite this templates as preprocess in xyz.theme?

These are the paths of the files.

- drupal/docroot/profiles/custom/project/themes/xyz/xyz.theme
- drupal/docroot/profiles/custom/project/themes/xyz/templates/header-before-login.html.twig
- drupal/docroot/profiles/custom/project/themes/xyz/templates/header-after-login.html.twig

Comment: `function xyz_preprocess_header_before_login(array &$variables)`

Comment: I tried. It's not working. In header.html.twig. I'm including both this templates. If logged in then calling after-login template elase before-login template. I even tried with `function xyz_preprocess_header(array &$variables)` & cleared cache as well. Still not working

Comment: How are those templates called? Is it really a template that you call from PHP or is it just a twig include, then you can't preprocess it.

Comment: It's just twig include. Not called from PHP. Now we are actually on point. I think

Comment: Yes, that's not a template as far as Drupal is concerned, there's no preprocess or anything like that. I guess you should be able to implement preprocess of the template that includes them and provide the variables there, but you might need to pass them through to the other, don't know how that works in detail in twig.

Comment: Thanks @Berdir. So what will be alternative solution for this.